# GIT Failed To Update Files Silently on git pull Due to File Permissions

Tags: linux, git, file-permissions

git user did not have the permissions to update files that were to be pulled from the remote repository. It did not give any warning on git pull. Now the permissions are fixed, but the files in the working dir have not changed. I tried `git reset --hard HEAD`, but it did not help. The files are still the old ones.

What to do now to update the files in the working dir to match those in the repository?

Comment: If the update to the working tree failed, Git should not have recorded any update to the working tree, and `git reset --hard` should proceed. But if something really bizarre happened, you can always remove all the working tree files, *then* use `git reset --hard`. Be very careful with this as any *untracked* files you might remove here aren't *in* Git and therefore cannot be restored *by* Git. It's much safer to *move* the files elsewhere (which removes them from the working tree, but keeps them in that "elsewhere").

Comment: This kind of failure-to-update is never *silent* either, so there's something else going on, not captured in your problem description.